# Changing file name and URL structure

Tags: php, url

I just created a website with the help from a developer. We are creating the site based on existing script that I bought from a company.

There are 3 things that I want to achieve regarding the URL.

1. I would like to change this: `http://cashduit.com/view_retailer.php?id=11` to `http://cashduit.com/agoda`
2. I also dont't want to show the file extension. For example: `http://cashduit.com/about-us.php` to `http://cashduit.com/about-us`
3. As it was existing script, I would like to know steps that I should take to change the name of a certain file. My thought is if I want to change this file name, I have to go to every other page file and if there is any track of the old file name, I need to change to the new one so it won't link to the old file name, am I right or there is any other way?. For example: public_html/about-us.php to public_html/aboutus.php and I have to go to every other files and replace any link to about-us.php to aboutus.php

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead, you could just do it via .htaccess and save yourself the trouble of breaking something in the script. It's hard to tell what can and can't be changed without looking at the script itself

Comment: you must change write a command in the htaccess file of your website

Comment: @Craig changing only `.htaccess` doesn't solve anything. The rewrite rules "unpack" a SEO-friendly URL into a query string but the application is the one that generates the URLs. It also needs to be changed to generate the URLs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)